# summing together counter_caches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So... I have 3 models.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
  has_many :bazs
end

class Baz < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar, counter_cache: true
end
```

So, I'd like a column for my Foo that behaves like a `bars_count`, except I want to add the `bazs_count` of `Bar` together, instead of the `.size`. Do I have to go manual here, with a `before_save` or something? Is there something with this functionality already in Rails?

So, if there are 2 bars... 1 has a `bazs_count = 4`, and another with `bazs_count = 8`.  If both of those bars belong to a foo, I'd like to have `bars_count = 12` whenever the `bazs_count` changes.

Reason being... I'll often be checking how many bazs a particular foo has, and I'd like to keep the querying minimal.

Comment: nops, there isn't, you have to do this manually yourself.

Comment: k... so when the `counter_cache` updates the bar, it's not actually saving, so my `after_save` call on Bar doesn't trigger.  If I `Bar.find(1).save` afterwards, then it updates Foo properly. How should that be triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the following methods to your Baz model to increment and decrement the `bazs_count` column in your Foo model. I found that Rails pluralises baz to bazs, not bazes.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo, counter_cache: true
  has_many :bazs
end

class Baz < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar, counter_cache: true

  after_create :increment_foo_counter
  after_destroy :decrement_foo_counter

  private

  def increment_foo_counter
    Foo.increment_counter(:bazs_count, bar.foo_id)
  end

  def decrement_foo_counter
    Foo.decrement_counter(:bazs_count, bar.foo_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Nailed it.  I tried doing some other funky method that rewrote the counter_cache method.  This does exactly what I was after, thank you so much! It's cool to see the `.increment_counter` method in action, and how it can be called like that.

Comment: for that matter... if I wanted, I could actually remove the `counter_cache` on Baz if I wasn't ever going to call it. Very nice.